# What causes Google Sheets API Traceback/Refresh Error?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

Hi I am high school senior and I want to do a small program for a school project.

I need to get information from a google sheet into my code. I followed this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnPlKLEGR7E) to try to do this. I followed every step and put in all my info properly, but I keep getting this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Conner Boggan/Desktop/Senior Project/Python Code/Google Sheets/Sheets.py", line 11, in 
>       sheet = client.open("tpol2").sheet1  # Open the spreadhseet
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Android app\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 119, in open
>       self.list_spreadsheet_files(title),
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Android app\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 95, in list_spreadsheet_files
>       res = self.request('get', url, params=params).json()
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Android app\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 67, in request
>       headers=headers,
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Android app\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
>       return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Android app\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 440, in request
>       self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Android app\lib\site-packages\google\auth\credentials.py", line 124, in before_request
>       self.refresh(request)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Android app\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\service_account.py", line 334, in refresh
>       access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(request, self._token_uri, assertion)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Android app\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2_client.py", line 153, in jwt_grant
>       response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Android app\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2_client.py", line 124, in _token_endpoint_request
>       _handle_error_response(response_body)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Android app\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2_client.py", line 60, in _handle_error_response
>       raise exceptions.RefreshError(error_details, response_body)
>   google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.', '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim."}')

This is my code for reference:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("TPOL2.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("tpol2").sheet1  # Open the spreadhseet

data = sheet.get_all_records()  # Get a list of all records

print(data)
```

I can run each line except the last 3 which leads me to believe the code is able to get online properly, but there is something in the way between the code and the google sheet.

Any help would very much appreciated.